# Weird behaviour of zsh iteration over content of a variable

Tags: zsh

I have a weird behaiour with ZSH when iterating over the content of a variable. A demo is better than a long talk in this case, so here is my problem:

```
(yoann@freya) test_bash » ls
file1  file2  file3
(yoann@freya) test_bash » for f in $(ls); do echo $f-SUF; done
file1-SUF
file2-SUF
file3-SUF
(yoann@freya) test_bash » files=$(ls); for f in $files; do echo $f-SUF; done 
file1
file2
file3-SUF
(yoann@freya) test_bash »
```

I expect the second iteration to have the same result as the first one. I have tried the following:

- other people's ZSH (same distribution): worked fine
- with bash on my machine: worked fine
- remove my .zshrc: the problem persisted.
- if I do

  files=$(ls); for f in $(echo $files | tr '\n' ' '); do echo $f-SUF; done

it works fine. But once again, if I capture the result of the echo piped on tr, I only get one -SUF at the end.

I am really out of ideas about what is happening, does anyone have a clue ?

Thanks.

Some information:

- Distribution: debian Wheezy
- zsh version: zsh 4.3.17 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)

If it can be of any use:

```
(yoann@freya) test_bash » locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is a [bad idea to parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Instead use globbing (see section *FILENAME GENERATION* in `man zshexpn`), in your case

```
for f in *; do
  echo ${f}-SUP
done
```

The reason that both of your examples seem to work in bash (as long a there are no white spaces in your filenames etc.) is, that bash splits parameters on white spaces by default, 
which `zsh` does not do. You can get this behavior in `zsh`, too, with this option:

```
setopt SH_WORD_SPLIT
```

Explanation from `man zshoptions`

> **SH_WORD_SPLIT** Causes  field  splitting  to be performed on
>   unquoted parameter expansions.  Note that this option has nothing to
>   do with word splitting.  (See the section `Parameter Expansion'.)

*But please take the advices given in the above link seriously!*